# Unable to move and track data from one controller to another angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello ladies and geentlemen am stack here: i am trying to do the following
1) getBusinessses of a particular subcategory from the database. which i successfully do.
2) I get them from the `CategoryCtrl` and i want to display them on the search page which loads with the `SearchCtrl` i see the data in `CategoryCtrl` but fail to track it in the `SearchCtrl` i see nothing in `SearchCtrl`: here is my code. Someone please help me out

Html

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12" ng-controller="CategoryCtrl"> 

    <a hfref="#" style="text-decoration:none" ng-click="getBusinesses(sub_category.id)"   class="badblack">{{sub_category.name}}</a>

</div>
```

javascript

```
.controller('CategoryCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope','sharedproperties',function($scope,$rootScope,sharedproperties){

    $scope.getBusinesses=function(sub_category_id)
        {

            $http.get($scope.BaseURL+"classes/util.php?sub_category_id="+sub_category_id+"&transaction=get_businesses").then(function(results){

                    alert("results are"+results);
                    console.log("jsonstring axctualyy  is",results);
                    $scope.bus_es = results;
                    sharedProperties.setProperty($scope.bus_es.data);//successfully sets property
                    console.log("sharedProperty is",sharedProperties.getProperty());

                    $rootScope.$broadcast("CallSubcategoryBusinesses", $scope.bus_es.data);
                    window.location.href=BaseURL+"search.php";

            });


        }

}])
.controller('SearchCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope','sharedproperties',function($scope,$rootScope,sharedproperties)
{
    $rootScope.$on("CallSubcategoryBusinesses", function(event,data){

              //$scope.search_subCategory_businesses();
              //$scope.businesses=data;
              console.log("the data from categories is is",data)
             // alert($scope.search_subCategory_businesses());
        });

}])
.factory('sharedproperties',function()
{

        var property = '';

        return {
            getProperty: function () {
                return property;
            },
            setProperty: function(value) {
                property = value;
            }
        };


})
```

Comment: use a readable heading for the question.what u mean by another angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the following fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HEdJF/1605/

```
myApp.factory('Data', function(){
    return { FirstName: '' };
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){
    var mydata="Factory";
  Data.FirstName=mydata;
  $scope.Data = Data;
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){
    $scope.Data = Data;
});
```

Sharing of data can be done by using either factory or service...

Comment: It would be better if you even vote up for this..so that it will be usefull for others who have th same prob

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share data between controllers, you need to keep this data in a service, so at the same time both controllers can access the data. Another way is to use angular signal framework - e.g. in second controller on given event it reads data passed in the event.